# Iphone big XML files parsing efficiency

Tags: objective-c, xml, soap, iphone-sdk-3.0

I plan to develop an Iphone application which will communicate with my SOAP web service, it is a stateless web service which will each time send back and forth whole the state in the XML(a few hundreds of questions and their answers, types..etc. expected to be a 200-300kb of XML file I guess)

I plan to use WSDL2ObjC. Every time the user click next, it will send current XML, receive new XML and parse whole XML and print the latest question on the screen.

I do not know if it is something easily IPhone can handle to receive and parse whole 200-300KB size XML easily in every next click.

My questions is; in terms of **memory and CPU** can I have any problems? and which points should I be careful, which parsers should I use..etc

tnx

Comment: For parsing large XML docs, use a SAX parser, not a DOM parser.

Comment: can I hold 200-300kb xml in memory and parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously for big files, you do need to use a SAX parser and not DOM.

iOS SDK contains an Objective-C class (NSXMLParser) you can usually use to do SAX parsing.

But if you are concerned about performance, memory usage and CPU, you may compare it with other solutions like the libxml2 C library or other. **See [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) that compares existing XML parsing libraries** available for iOS and their performance. It should answer your question.

Comment: tnx how can I add libxml2 to my project?

Comment: Simply add libxml2.dylib in your project as you would do for adding any other lib or framework (Add Framework -> select the libxml2.dylib in the (long) list)

Comment: does 200-300KB relatively big to hold in memory?

Comment: Avoid holding the whole XML in memory. Prefer using SAX parsing, and fill your model with the parsed data (e.g. if your XML contains <book> tags, you may create a "Book" class in your model to hold the data, and fill it as you parse your XML. You will then keep your Book instances, not the XML itself)

Comment: Tnx, could you have a look my question about WSDL2ObjC generated code? still no answer..

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'm using my own WS and never used WSDL2ObjC. Maybe try to bounty your question (see [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq))